# Most suitable combinatorics algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

There are 6 seats and 4 persons, for which seats must be allocated according to some optimality criterion. For example:

```
Allocation 1:
_ _ _ _ _ _
1 2   3 4 

Allocation 2:
_ _ _ _ _ _
1 3   2   4 

...
```

Question 1: Which combinatorics problem is it?

Question 2: What is the name of most suitable algorithm for searching through all possible combinations?

Comment: Sounds like a maximum weight matching to me, assuming the weights of assignments are independent of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) k-permutation of n without repetion:
http://www.statlect.com/comdis1.htm

2.) It depends on which you are searching for. For example, I offer you genetic algorithms which can find the best candidate based on a special heuristic if you can order a "goodness degree" to the possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, but I think k-permutiation is right. Your answer writes that `4!(6 choose 2) = 4! * (6! / (4! * 2!)) = 6! / 2! = n! / (n-k)!` which is exactly the solution of k-permutation of n.

Answer (score 1):

To answer Question 1, note that for the sequence of 4 persons there are `4!` possibilites. Additionally, the `6-4=2` non-occupied seats must be positioned between the people, for which there are `4+1=5` slots (before every person and behind the last person), resulting in `5+2-1 choose 2` possibilities, where `choose` denotes the binomial coeffiecient, by interpretation as [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem. In total, there are

`4!(6 choose 2)`

possibilities, or parameterized

`m!(m+1+n-m-1 choose n-m) = m!(n choose n-m)`

where `m` is the number of people and `n` is the number of seats; using the identity

`n choose k = n!/(k!(n-k)!)`

this can be simplified to

`n!/(n-m)!`

which is indeed the `n`-permutation of `m` objects as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Concerning Question 2, this really depends on the optimality criterion and whether an exact, approximate or heuristic algorithm is desired.

Comment: Do you know which algorithm may help searching through all possible combinations?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Please see my updated answer, I mixed something up but corrected it.

Comment: All you sure that you parameterized solution is right? It does not mach with the numerical version. `m!(**n** choose **n-m**)` fits better, no?

Comment: @TiborTakács Let me think it over. Unfortunately, I currently have neither paper nor pencil available.